# How do I solve SCRIPT1003?

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, webpack, babeljs

there are similar questions about this issue, but none seems to really solve the issue.

Got a project with VueJS, built with ES6 syntax and transpiled with BabeJS, then bundled up with Webpack.

Here some specs,

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.5.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.6.2",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.2",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
        "autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
        "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^5.1.0",
        "babel-template": "^6.26.0",
        "chalk": "^2.4.2",
        "compression-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
        "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.5.1",
        "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^4.0.1",
        "eslint-loader": "^2.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.1.0",
        "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "jest": "^24.8.0",
        "jest-serializer-vue": "^2.0.2",
        "js-yaml": "^3.12.1",
        "jsdom": "^13.2.0",
        "lint-staged": "^9.4.1",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.7.0",
        "node-env-tools": "^1.0.2",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
        "ora": "^3.4.0",
        "portfinder": "^1.0.20",
        "postcss": "^7.0.17",
        "postcss-assets": "^5.0.0",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "postcss-url": "^8.0.0",
        "prettier": "^1.16.4",
        "pug": "^2.0.4",
        "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
        "sass-lint": "^1.12.1",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "semver": "^5.6.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
        "text-table": "^0.2.0",
        "url-loader": "^2.0.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-eslint-parser": "^6.0.4",
        "vue-jest": "^3.0.4",
        "vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
        "vue-prop-sep": "^1.0.2",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.2",
        "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-template-es2015-compiler": "^1.9.1",
        "webpack": "^4.41.0",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.5.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2",
        "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
    }
```

babelrc:

```
{
    "env": {
        "test": {
            "plugins": [
                "istanbul"
            ]
        }
    },
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "debug": true,
                "modules": false,
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 10"]
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ]
}
```

Presets debug traces:

```
Using targets:
{
  "android": "76",
  "chrome": "76",
  "edge": "17",
  "firefox": "68",
  "ie": "10",
  "ios": "12.2",
  "opera": "12.1",
  "safari": "12.1",
  "samsung": "9.2"
}

Using modules transform: false

Using plugins:
  transform-template-literals { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "ios":"12.2", "opera":"12.1", "safari":"12.1" }
  transform-literals { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-function-name { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-arrow-functions { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-block-scoped-functions { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-classes { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-object-super { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-shorthand-properties { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-duplicate-keys { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-computed-properties { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-for-of { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-sticky-regex { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-dotall-regex { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-unicode-regex { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-spread { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-parameters { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-destructuring { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-block-scoping { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-typeof-symbol { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-new-target { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-regenerator { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-exponentiation-operator { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  proposal-async-generator-functions { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  proposal-object-rest-spread { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  proposal-unicode-property-regex { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1", "samsung":"9.2" }
  proposal-json-strings { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1", "samsung":"9.2" }
  proposal-optional-catch-binding { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1", "samsung":"9.2" }
  transform-named-capturing-groups-regex { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1", "samsung":"9.2" }
  syntax-dynamic-import { "android":"76", "chrome":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "ios":"12.2", "opera":"12.1", "safari":"12.1", "samsung":"9.2" }

Using polyfills: No polyfills were added, since the `useBuiltIns` option was not set.
```

Testing the browser configuration, here https://browserl.ist/?q=%3E+1%25%2C+last+2+versions%2C+not+ie+%3C%3D+10, it is supposed to work on IE11, but it doesn't.

Also, bootstrap-vue is used in project.

IMO it seems that altough Babel is using right browserlist configuration, at some point, is not using it properly, maybe webpack is overriding the configuration.

¿Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**:

I have changed @babel/preset-env configuration and added `core-js`.

Debug traces output this:

```
Using targets:
{
  "android": "76",
  "chrome": "76",
  "edge": "17",
  "firefox": "68",
  "ie": "10",
  "ios": "12.2",
  "opera": "12.1",
  "safari": "12.1",
  "samsung": "9.2"
}

Using modules transform: auto

Using plugins:
  transform-template-literals { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "ios":"12.2", "opera":"12.1", "safari":"12.1" }
  transform-literals { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-function-name { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-arrow-functions { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-block-scoped-functions { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-classes { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-object-super { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-shorthand-properties { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-duplicate-keys { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-computed-properties { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-for-of { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-sticky-regex { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-dotall-regex { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-unicode-regex { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-spread { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-parameters { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-destructuring { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-block-scoping { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-typeof-symbol { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-new-target { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-regenerator { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  transform-exponentiation-operator { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  proposal-async-generator-functions { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  proposal-object-rest-spread { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  proposal-unicode-property-regex { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1", "samsung":"9.2" }
  proposal-json-strings { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1", "samsung":"9.2" }
  proposal-optional-catch-binding { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1", "samsung":"9.2" }
  transform-named-capturing-groups-regex { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1", "samsung":"9.2" }
  syntax-dynamic-import { "android":"76", "chrome":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "ios":"12.2", "opera":"12.1", "safari":"12.1", "samsung":"9.2" }

Using polyfills with `usage` option:

  When setting `useBuiltIns: 'usage'`, polyfills are automatically imported when needed.
  Please remove the direct import of `core-js` or use `useBuiltIns: 'entry'` instead.

[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/index.js] Based on your code and targets, core-js polyfills were not added.
12% building 19/25 modules 6 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/html-entities/index.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/router.js] Based on your code and targets, core-js polyfills were not added.
12% building 21/27 modules 6 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/plugins/env-config.js] Based on your code and targets, core-js polyfills were not added.
40% building 223/249 modules 26 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/toast/toaster.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/views/product-selection/script.js] Added following core-js polyfills:
  es.array.find { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.includes { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.object.to-string { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.promise { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.string.includes { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }

[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/views/product-selection/script.js] Based on your code and targets, added regenerator-runtime.
40% building 224/249 modules 25 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/toast/toaster.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/app/script.js] Based on your code and targets, core-js polyfills were not added.
40% building 225/249 modules 24 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/toast/toaster.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/views/product-confirmation/script.js] Based on your code and targets, core-js polyfills were not added.
40% building 226/249 modules 23 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/toast/toaster.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/views/sms-confirmation/script.js] Based on your code and targets, core-js polyfills were not added.
40% building 227/249 modules 22 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/toast/toaster.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/views/home/script.js] Based on your code and targets, core-js polyfills were not added.
40% building 228/249 modules 21 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/toast/toaster.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/views/process-check/script.js] Added following core-js polyfills:
  es.array.concat { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.includes { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.some { "opera":"12.1" }
  es.object.keys { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.object.to-string { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.promise { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.regexp.exec { "opera":"12.1" }
  es.string.includes { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.string.replace { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "ios":"12.2", "opera":"12.1", "safari":"12.1" }
  es.string.split { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }

[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/views/process-check/script.js] Based on your code and targets, added regenerator-runtime.
40% building 229/249 modules 20 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/toast/toaster.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/views/entities/script.js] Added following core-js polyfills:
  es.object.to-string { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.promise { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }

[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/views/entities/script.js] Based on your code and targets, added regenerator-runtime.
40% building 237/252 modules 15 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/vue-functional-data-merge/dist/lib.esm.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/views/entity-login/script.js] Added following core-js polyfills:
  es.array.concat { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.for-each { "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.includes { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.join { "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.last-index-of { "android":"76", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.map { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.some { "opera":"12.1" }
  es.date.to-string { "opera":"12.1" }
  es.function.name { "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.object.assign { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.object.keys { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.object.to-string { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.promise { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.regexp.exec { "opera":"12.1" }
  es.regexp.to-string { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.string.includes { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.string.replace { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "ios":"12.2", "opera":"12.1", "safari":"12.1" }
  web.dom-collections.for-each { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }

[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/views/entity-login/script.js] Based on your code and targets, added regenerator-runtime.
46% building 303/321 modules 18 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/tooltip/helpers/bv-popper.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/mixins/robots.js] Added following core-js polyfills:
  es.array.filter { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.find { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.includes { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.index-of { "android":"76", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.sort { "android":"76", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.function.name { "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.object.to-string { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.promise { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.string.includes { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }

[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/mixins/robots.js] Based on your code and targets, added regenerator-runtime.
46% building 304/321 modules 17 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/tooltip/helpers/bv-popper.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/mixins/is-error.js] Added following core-js polyfill:
  es.array.concat { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
46% building 305/321 modules 16 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/tooltip/helpers/bv-popper.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/mixins/eur-codes.js] Added following core-js polyfills:
  es.object.to-string { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.promise { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.regexp.exec { "opera":"12.1" }
  es.string.match { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }

[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/mixins/eur-codes.js] Based on your code and targets, added regenerator-runtime.
46% building 307/334 modules 27 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/core-js/modules/es.regexp.to-string.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/mixins/delayed-request.js] Added following core-js polyfills:
  es.object.to-string { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.promise { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }

[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/mixins/delayed-request.js] Based on your code and targets, added regenerator-runtime.
63% building 451/503 modules 52 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/core-js/internals/array-species-create.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/components/accounts-list/script.js] Based on your code and targets, core-js polyfills were not added.
64% building 453/503 modules 50 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/core-js/internals/array-species-create.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/components/app-footer/script.js] Based on your code and targets, core-js polyfills were not added.
64% building 455/503 modules 48 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/core-js/internals/array-species-create.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/components/app-header/script.js] Based on your code and targets, core-js polyfills were not added.
64% building 456/503 modules 47 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/core-js/internals/array-species-create.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/components/entity-logo/script.js] Based on your code and targets, core-js polyfills were not added.
64% building 457/503 modules 46 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/core-js/internals/array-species-create.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/components/account-detail/script.js] Based on your code and targets, core-js polyfills were not added.
67% building 523/544 modules 21 active /home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/core-js/internals/create-property-descriptor.js
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/mixins/app-close.js] Added following core-js polyfills:
  es.array.concat { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.join { "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.array.map { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.object.keys { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
  es.regexp.exec { "opera":"12.1" }
  es.string.replace { "android":"76", "edge":"17", "firefox":"68", "ie":"10", "ios":"12.2", "opera":"12.1", "safari":"12.1" }
68% building 551/567 modules 16 active ...its/cobranding/webportal-2.0/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--4-3!/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/components/accounts-list-item/style.sass?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass&
[/home/arturom/Projects/com.gitlab/eurobits/cobranding/webportal-2.0/src/components/accounts-list-item/script.js] Added following core-js polyfill:
  es.number.constructor { "android":"76", "ie":"10", "opera":"12.1" }
98% after emitting CopyPlugin
```

**UPDATE (2019-11-26)**:

This is my `.babelrc` configuration right now:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "debug": true,
                "modules": false,
                "useBuiltIns": "entry",
                "corejs": 3,
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": "> 1%, last 2 versions, not ie <= 10"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I have added both `core-js` and `@babel/polyfill` to devDependencies. Also I have added `@babel/polyfill` to my entry point file. Still having *SCRIPT1003* error in IE11.

Comment: Can you debug your code and find which part of code or what kind of syntax actually raised this error? Before using the webpack, whether the application works well in IE browser? Besides, since you are using ES6 syntax, generally, we could try to use the [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl) to translate this part of the code to ES5 or try to install the "babel/polyfill". then, Use useBuiltIns: 'entry' and then adds import '@babel/polyfill' to your entry file.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT The **SCRIPT1003** issue is related to shorthands sintax in objects, i.e.: `var a = 1; var b = { a };`. As you can see in the `dependencies` I am already using Babel and `@babel/preset-env`. `@babel/polyfill` is _deprecated_ and is suggested to use `core-js`, which I have already tried and it still translates badly the output.

Comment: About this code `var a = 1; var b = { a };`, you could change it to `var a = 1; var b = { a :a };` by yourself. Since the IE browser doesn't support ES6 syntax, please try to configure to build/run your application using ES5 syntax. You could refer [babel/preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) or [this article](https://medium.com/@onlykiosk/complete-babel-7-guide-for-beginners-in-2019-7dd78214c464). Besides, please check the package.json, make sure it contains IE11 browser support, like this: `{
  "targets": {
    "chrome": "58",
    "ie": "11"
  }
}`

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT so your suggestion is to fix by myself something that Babel should translate itself ...

Comment: You may have solved this as it was a while back but I just had the same issue and found it was to do with the optimisation step in webpack not keeping es5 in mind when minifying (hence shortening long form object syntax to shorthand). I had to set `terserOptions: { ecma: 5, },` in my optimisation config to resolve this.